# How long do access tokens last in the Spotify API Implicit Grant Flow?

Tags: spotify

I'm intending to use the Spotify Web API and looking at the Implicit Grant Flow, which says it is implemented for JS apps. It states that the issued access tokens are short-lived, and I was wondering how long they actually last for to see if this is a viable option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotify's access tokens are valid for one hour.